# How to specify a different repository for Docker push?

Tags: docker

I have a private repository here:

https://hub.docker.com/r/istvan/xxx/

When I build and image and trying to push it there it fails with the following:

```
docker login
sudo docker push istvan:xxx
```

The error is:

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/library/istvan]
2456c4c8fd2b: Preparing
5903f32c0854: Preparing
549bd34bfa87: Preparing
08586c0f628f: Preparing
2aebd096e0e2: Preparing
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tag the image that you are trying to push to include the repository name:

```
docker tag <image> <username>/<image-name>:<tag>
```

And then you push the tagged image:

```
docker push <username>/<image-name>:<tag>
```